# How can I solve Error in loading marker on worker 404

Tags: aframe, ar.js, web-ar

I uploaded my project to the server but I am getting an error 'Error in loading marker on worker 404' I'm working on a WebAR project using A-Frame and AR.js. I'm facing challenges loading an NFT marker. The relevant code snippets are provided below.

```
<!-- demo  -->


<!--  -->
<!-- three.js marker link  -->
<!--     -->

<!-- three.js nts/ image link -->
<!-- <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-
nft.js"></script> -->
<title>WEBAR TEST</title>



<!-- <h1>Web AR test one</h1> -->

<a-scene embedded arjs>
    <!-- <a-marker preset="hiro"> -->
    <!-- <a-marker custome="preset"  type="pattern" url="./image/pattern-SAF-LOGO.patt"> -->
        <a-nft
            type="nft"
            url="./image/nfts/logos"
            smooth="true"
            smoothCount="10"
            smoothTolerance=".01"
            smoothThreshold="5">

       <!-- <a-box position="0 0.5 0" scale="100 100 100" material="color: red"
       animation="property: rotation; dur: 4000; to: 360 360 0; loop: true; repeat:  
       indefinite; easing: linear;">  
            </a-box> -->

            <a-entity geometry="primitive: box; width: 100; height: 100; depth: 100"
                      position="0 0.5 0"
                      material="color: red"
                      animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; repeat: 
                      indefinite; dur: 5000">
            </a-entity>

        </a-nft>
        <a-entity camera>
        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
```